# "Cannot find or create the font" error in Adobe Reader

Tags: windows-8, pdf, adobe-reader

I am using PDFsharp to add text to a PDF. After the PDF is created, I open it with Adobe Reader. I'm getting a message like

> Cannot find or create the font 'Wingdings'. Some characters may not display or print correctly.

But in Windows 8's PDF reader app it opens without problems. The PDF properly displays all fonts.

Why does this error appear, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I reopened the question, but you might want to give us more details, such as the version of Adobe Reader, and possibly an example PDF that exhibits the error.